# Selenium IDE: want X-path for links to open in different window but ids, class, identifier of all ads are same

Tags: xpath, selenium, selenium-rc, selenium-ide

how to write X-path for number of ads links on same page and there is not unique id and Unique name to differentiate in HTML code, I have written below, please provide unique value to "click" ad and open ad in new window, as all ads have class="ad" and value is dynamic please help me out, as i want to open all ads one by one and verify data in 
I have expanded only two ads and all other ads collapse

example:

```
<div class="result hlisting">

<div class="result hlisting">

<div class="info">

<h2>

#11856006:

<a class="ad" href="http://www.performancecars.ca/index.php/details/11856006/2009-Toyota-Camry.html">2009 Toyota Camry</a>

</h2>

<span class="price"> 14.584 CAD </span>

<p class="address">

<b>Date: </b>

2012-10-09 13:29:01 

</p>

</div>

<p class="description">

<p class="data">

<div class="clear"> </div>

<hr>

</div>

<div class="result hlisting">

<div class="result hlisting">

<div class="info">

<h2>

#11930827:

<a class="ad" href="http://www.performancecars.ca/index.php/details/11930827/2010-Mazda-MAZDA3.html">2010 Mazda MAZDA3 GS ONE OWNER, SU.</a>

</h2>

<span class="price"> 14.200 CAD </span>

<p class="address">

</div>

<p class="description">

<p class="data">

<div class="clear"> </div>

<hr>

</div>

<div class="result hlisting">

<div class="result hlisting">
```

Comment: Why not use in class attribute? like this XPath: `//a[@class='ad']`

Answer (score 0):

You can you use the link name -

```
link, '2009 Toyota Camry' 
link, '2010 Mazda MAZDA3 GS ONE OWNER, SU.'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<WebElement> allLinks=driver.findElements(By.className("ads"));
for(WebElement e:ele)
{
    e.click();  //click on ad link
    //do your operations on particular ad page
    //go to home page again
}
```

The above logic will click on every link available on that page.

Comment: Using getXpathCount get the total count of links and then run the loop for clicking on every link (In loop based on index can locate each individual link).

Answer (score 0):

i would try using css selectors:

```
String toyotaCss = "a[href='http://www.performancecars.ca/index.php/details/11856006/2009-Toyota-Camry.html']"
String mazdaCss="a[href='http://www.performancecars.ca/index.php/details/11930827/2010-Mazda-MAZDA3.html']";
```

Hope this works for you

Answer (score 0):

For links u can simply locate by writing,,
link='text of your link'...It works fine

Answer (score 0):

If you know the text of the links, you could try something like

```
selenium.click(selenium.getAttribute("//*[text()='" + link + "']/ancestor::a@href") + " _blank");
```

To open in new window, u need to append `_blank` to the href.

If you want to click on all the links in the page no matter what the text is, simply iterate over the xpath count

```
selenium.click(selenium.getAttribute("xpath=(//a)[" + iterator + "]@href") + " _blank");
```